# Duplicate a document in MongoDB using a new _id

Tags: mongodb

Ok, I suppose that this is a silly question and probably has a simple answer.

How can I duplicate a document in MongoDB, changing the _id of the new one?

Imaging that you have the original document:

```
> var orig = db.MyCollection.findOne({_id: 'hi'})
```

And now I want another document in the collection with _id 'bye'.

Answer (score 114):

Just change the id and re-insert.

```
> db.coll.insert({_id: 'hi', val: 1})
> var orig = db.coll.findOne({_id: 'hi'})
> orig._id = 'bye'
bye
> db.coll.insert(orig)
> db.coll.find()
{ "_id" : "hi", "val" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "bye", "val" : 1 }
```

Comment: If you want to clone the row, but without explicitely typing a new id, just delete the "_id" property before doing the insert command: delete orig._id

Answer (score 41):

A little improvement to the @689 response

```
var copy = db.collection.findOne({},{_id:0});
for (var i = 0; i< 30; i++){ 
    db.collection.insert(copy);
}
```

Comment: I don't see how.

Each insert creates a new and unic _id.

Comment: add `delete copy._id`

Comment: with `{_id: 0}` there is no need of `delete copy._id` because the _id is not fetched

Comment: If I run this script, it will just duplicate the same document 30 times. How can I modify this to duplicate 100 different documents (any documents)?

Comment: For light users, `collection` in the code above has to be replaced by your actual collection name.

Comment: @ShubhamA. You should ask a new question but...

`db.collection.find({}, {_id: 0}).limit(100).forEach(db.collection.insert)`

not tested.

Answer (score 38):

You can give a new ObjectId to the copy Document. In mongo shell

```
var copy = db.collection.findOne();
for (var i = 0; i< 30; i++){ 
    copy._id = new ObjectId(); 
    db.collection.insert(copy);
}
```

Comment: First var should be const. Great solution though!

Answer (score 25):

You can use below code :

**Run using single line :**

```
db.collectionName.find({"_id" : ObjectId("5a4e47e0a21698d455000009")}).forEach(function(doc){var newDoc = doc; delete newDoc._id; db.collectionName.insert(newDoc); })
```

**a structural format for understanding :**

```
db.collectionName.find({"_id" : ObjectId("5a4e47e0a21698d455000009")}).forEach(function(doc){
    var newDoc = doc;
    delete newDoc._id;
    db.collectionName.insert(newDoc);
})
```

Answer (score 4):

Many of the previous answers are simple and correct, but they are not efficient if your goal is to copy **all the documents in the collection** with new `_id`s.  Here is a three-line solution that was more than 10x faster for me:

First copy the collection efficiently:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{ $out: "collection_copy" }]);
```

Now pass documents from the copy back into the original, but remove the `_id` field so a new `_id` is generated:

```
db.collection_copy.aggregate([{$project: {_id: 0}}, { $merge: "collection" }]);
```

Finally, clean up the copy:

```
db.collection_copy.drop();
```

Answer (score 1):

In mongo shell: **It's OK**

```
db.products.find().forEach( function(doc){db.products.insert(
{
    "price":doc.price,
    "name":doc.name,
    "typeName":doc.typeName,
    "image":doc.image
}
)} );
```

Answer (score 0):

single line

```js
(function(doc){delete doc._id; db.collection.insert(doc)})(db.collection.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("60c9a684c7d51907c35ad463")}))
```

structured

```
(function(doc) {
  delete doc._id;
  db.collection.insert(doc);
})(db.collection.findOne({ _id: ObjectId('60c9a684c7d51907c35ad463') }));

// (function(doc){...})(doc)
```

Comment: Can someone explain what I did wrong? please

Answer (score 0):

With a pipeline

```
db.collection.insertMany(
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { _id: ObjectId("") }
    },
     
 { $unset: [ "_id"] }]).toArray());
```