# duplicate a collection into itself

Tags: mongodb

How can I copy a mongodb collection into itself with clashes in `_id` resolved by a new `_id`?
Copying individual documents using [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11763384/duplicate-a-document-in-mongodb-using-a-new-id) is not feasible for large collections.
I want to do this to increase the size of the testing sample in a contrived manner, this is just for testing the scalability. So I thought, instead of adding new documents, I could duplicate the collection into itself a few times to achieve the purpose.

Comment: Why would you want to "copy" all the content again with different `_id` values in the same collection? Be specific in your question or you will get a wrong answer.

Comment: @NeilLunn - I added the reason why I want to do it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to generate plausible data for test purposes, here's a handy recipe using some command line tools:

- [`mongodb-schema`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb-schema) to infer a probablistic schema for an existing collection
- [`morelikethis`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/morelikethis) to convert that schema to a template
- [`mgeneratejs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mgeneratejs) to generate new documents according to a schema template
- [`mongoimport`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/) to import the new documents into MongoDB

`mongoimport` is a part of the standard MongoDB command line tools; the first three tools are installable from `npm`:

```
npm install -g morelikethis mongodb-schema mgeneratejs
```

Sample usage to generate 1,000 new documents based on an analysis of the existing documents:

> mongodb-schema localhost:27017 mydb.mycollection | morelikethis | mgeneratejs -n 1000 | mongoimport -d mydb -c mycollection

If you don't have any test data yet (or prefer to describe the shape of new documents) you could always skip the schema analysis and start with `mgeneratejs` and `mongoimport`.