# mongodb - shard key - compound vs hash

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I am working with an existing mongodb collection. The  data looks like the following:

```
{ user_id: 123, post: { id: 123456789, title: "..." } },
{ user_id: 123, post: { id: 123456790, title: "..." } },
{ user_id: 124, post: { id: 123456791, title: "..." } }
```

I need to shard this collection, and I'm having trouble selecting a shard key. I often perform operations based on a user (e.g. get all posts from user 123). Should I create a shard key based on

```
{
  user_id: 1,
  post.id: 1
}
```

or the same, but hashed?

If it is hashed I assume that range-queries will be broadcast to all shards. But if it is **not** hashed, will documents be evenly distributed across shards? You can see the values increase monotonically.

Thanks,

EDIT: I think I made a mistake, it appears composite indexes **cannot** be hashed. From the documentation (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound):

> You may not create compound indexes that have hashed index type. You will receive an error if you attempt to create a compound index that includes a hashed

I guess that means that this question is not sensible, so I'll close.

EDIT 2: On second thought, the question is valid, but it would be better phrased like so - I appear to have two options:

1. Hash the post.id field, which should be unique, and if hashed will help ensure even distribution of data across shards, or
2. Create a composite key of user_id and post.id, like the code above. This will also guarantee uniqueness, and should help with data locality for a single user. **But will it ensure even data distribution across shards?**

Thanks

Comment: Do you make range based queries on user_uid?

Comment: No, only per-user (i.e. get all posts from user 123), or 'where user_id IN (1,2,3)'

Comment: The best way to try out things is to test with your data, with all best-chosen shard keys and then trying those queries to check for scatter-gather or single shard hit :)

Comment: Sure, thanks. Generally speaking, in the above scenario, does a composite shard key make sense? For example, if I was to use "user_id" as the shard key, I would guarantee that all the posts for a given user are on the same shard. But then how would I guarantee uniqueness? I'm still new to sharding and I would hate to select a bad shard key. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Hash the post.id field, which should be unique, and if hashed will help ensure even distribution of data across shards

If your IDs are monotonic (as per the current examples) I would strongly consider using [UUIDs/GUIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) which can be generated without relying on a central sequence. Unless your sequence numbers are being supplied by another system of record, they will introduce a scaling and coordination challenge for distributed clients that need to claim the next available number. GUIDs would more effectively achieve the outcome you are aiming for with hashing.

MongoDB's default [`ObjectId`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) is one example designed for this purpose: a pseudo-random 12-byte value that can be independently generated in a distributed environment with some approximate ordering based on a leading timestamp.

Generating custom UUIDs is outside the scope of MongoDB, but if you have other requirements (length, range of values, ordering, likelihood of collision, ...) there are many available algorithms/libraries for generating UUIDs or you can create your own formula.

The *cardinality* of shard key values determines whether you will get effective data distribution. A hashed shard key helps distribute initial writes assuming there is cardinality in the original values: this basically changes a sequence from monotonically increasing to uniform.

> Create a composite key of user_id and post.id, like the code above. This will also guarantee uniqueness, and should help with data locality for a single user. **But will it ensure even data distribution across shards?**

A shard key requires high cardinality, but does not necessarily have to be unique. For example, if you shard on a single field which is `{month:1}` (representing months of the year) there are only 12 possible values for this field. All data for a single month will end up on a single shard so if there are more values for month 5 than month 11 the data distribution will be inherently uneven. MongoDB's [data distribution](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-balancer-administration/) for a sharded collection is based on being able to automatically divide the shard key into progressively smaller key ranges (called *chunks*). An underlying assumption is that each chunk represents a roughly equivalent range of data (on average) and that even distribution of chunks across shards will result in balance.

For your use case, `{user_id, post.id}` seems a likely composite shard key assuming you address the issue of monotonically increasing IDs. This would appear to meet the three aspects I mentioned above.

However, rather than guessing about shard key outcomes I would suggest testing this in a development environment.

If you have good understanding or estimation of your data model and distribution patterns, I would suggest sharding in a test environment using representative data. There are many helpful tools for generating fake (but probabilistic) data if needed. For an example recipe using schema analysis and a "more like this" approach, see: [duplicate a collection into itself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44895242/1388319).

Comment: Thanks again, Stennie. Would a reasonable solution be to create an extra field like `user_id_hash = CryptoJS.MD5(user_id);`, and then a unique composite shard key on `{user_id_hash, post.id}`? This would be easy to apply to existing documents, would mitigate the scaling issue, and would help with data locality. Thx

Comment: @mils Yes, reasonable solution if you already have existing documents. You'll need to add your hash values before creating the shard key index, and values in the shard key index will be immutable once the collection is sharded.