# How to do a document versioning in MongoDB using Driver

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, findoneandupdate

Requires `document` versioning in `MongoDB` while editing on the app.

I have many "Cards" created by various users. A card can be edited at any point. The app must hold all the changes in the database so that an admin can roll back to old changes.

To do that I have tried to copy and existing `document` which represents one card, reinsert it with a different `_id` which will be considered version 0. Then update the copied one with latest changes. This was I expect db to hold version 1, 2, 3 of the same `document`. I say same document because I am copying the first document's _id as   "source_id" for later to accumulate the result.

Using `MongoDB.Driver` with `VB.Net`

Although this hasn't worked, but is it a correct way to do?

Issues: `FindOneAndUpdate` returns the updated `document` and I lose the initial data.

Saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11763384/1108500) about how to duplicate a document, but this didn't work for me. Saw many places mentioned `upsert`, but the following didn't work for me either.

Comment: Your question does not make sense at all.

Comment: There is an excellent article by Asya (who apparently works for MongoDB) on tracking versions in MongoDB. http://www.askasya.com/post/trackversions/. It is a gem and a must read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

While editing an existing Card, create a new with incremented version. So use `InsertOne` method. Find the existing card, change certain fields that required to make the card latest before insert. Use a filed that allows card to be different from the rest. Let's user "status", which can be "published"/"draft"/"reject". Now in this case, change "status" field (from "Published" to "Draft") and increment the "version" field. No need to use "FindOneAndUpdate" because this will make the initial data lost.

This way in db there will be same card details with first card's ID as a resource id with different versions.