# Duplicate a document DB using MongoDB Model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to duplicate a document from MongoDB Model in NodeJS, below is the structure

```
{
    "_id": "62fe22f4b3c0fabfd1222d40", // this needs to be replaced in duplicated document
    "id": 1, // this is auto increment field, needs to be generated new auto increment field
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Cake",
    "ppu": 0.55,
    "batters":
        {
            "batter":
                [
                    { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                    { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" },
                    { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" },
                    { "id": "1004", "type": "Devil's Food" }
                ]
        },
    "topping":
        [
            { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
            { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
            { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },
            { "id": "5007", "type": "Powdered Sugar" },
            { "id": "5006", "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles" },
            { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
            { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
        ]
}
```

I did refer this [Duplicate a document in MongoDB using a new _id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11763384/duplicate-a-document-in-mongodb-using-a-new-id) post, however I am not sure of resetting auto increment id

Comment: Why would you use two different IDs and how is your auto increment implemented? As far as I know you cannot do this in MongoDB without a Trigger. https://www.mongodb.com/basics/mongodb-auto-increment

Comment: The autoincrement ID is used elsewhere in the application

MySchema.plugin(autoIncrement, { model: 'MyModel', field: 'id', startAt: 1 });

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use a NodeJS application you could do the following. Of course, if your `id` auto-increment is specified.:

```js
const { _id, id, __v, ...newMyObj } = await MyModel.findOne({ id }).lean();
await MyModel.create(newMyObj);
```

Comment: I dont have access to db.collection, instead only to Model. I tried below, it didnt work:

`
const newMyObj = await MyModel.findOne({ id }).exec();

  if (newMyObj && newMyObj !== null) {
    delete newMyObj._id;
    delete newMyObj.id;
    delete newMyObj.__v;

    await MyModel.create(newMyObj);
  }
`

Comment: What is the error you catch? Also I have updated my answer so it should work for you now

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the solution with below

```
const myDoc = await myModel.findOne({ id }).exec();

if (myDoc) {
const myDocObj = myDoc.toObject();
delete myDocObj._id;
delete myDocObj.id;

... continue deleting more unwanted props

return new myModel(myDocObj);

}

return null;
```